# Python descriptors for classes?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

We know we have protocol descriptors like `__get__` and `__getattr__` that can be used on class instances. Now is there a descriptor that is called on when accessing class attributes?

Say we have the following class:

```py
class Example:
    x = 1  # class attribute

    def __getattr__(self):
        return 2

# Example().x == 2
# Example.x == 1
```

What descriptor can I use to make `Example.x` return `2` ?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve, other than what `__get__` and `__getattr__` would get you to?

Comment: I added additional information , I hope it helps :)

Comment: Are you looking for the `@property` python decorator?

Comment: `__getattr__` is not a standard dunder method as far as I know.  Did you mean `__getattribute__`?

Comment: @renatodamas Are you trying to differentiate between class and instance attributes? They are kind of separate entities, e.g. [this](https://pastebin.com/L3Zu6BRm) will have the same effect. I still don't understand the usecase for that, though

Comment: @JohnGordon `__getattr__` is a standard dunder method. It it exists, the default `__getattribute__` will try it as the very final step before throwing an AttributeError. You can use it implement default (computed) attributes, but without having to completely override the attribute getting machinery. It's not a great idea to use it, as linters won't be able to understand, and devs may find it tricky to understand its use.

Answer (score 4):

The descriptor protocol can work on classes too, but you need to set the descriptor on class of the class. That is, you need to use metaclasses. The whole concept is the same, except the owner of the descriptor is the metaclass, and the instance involved is the class. However, the property will not be accessible from instance of the class.

For example:

```py
# this example uses a property to avoid having to define a custom descriptor
class MyMeta(type):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        print(self)
        return self.value

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        print(self, value)
        self.value = value * 3

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass

MyClass.foo = 'a'
assert MyClass.foo == 'aaa'

# instances no not get to see descriptor on the metaclass
assert not hasattr(MyClass(), 'foo')
```

If you want a **data** descriptor that works on both instances and classes then you are out of luck. If you only need a **non-data** descriptor (one that only defines `__get__`) then you can get by with defining the descriptor on the class.

For example:

```py
class NameTwice:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            # called directly on the class
            return owner.__name__ * 2
        else:
            # called on an instance
            return instance.name * 2

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    name_twice = NameTwice()

assert Foo.name_twice == 'FooFoo'
assert Foo(name='bar').name_twice == 'barbar'
```

Comment: great ! see a lot of work arounds - you can only bend the rules up to a certain point - but at least I can try to pick up on this :)

Comment: These are not "workarounds" - these are implemented according to the language specs, and use exactly the same rules the "ready to consumption" descriptors use for their working. It is just that if you need something with custom rules, you have to write the code for that.